# PC relative addressing in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, addressing-mode

from what I have learnt about PC relative addressing in MIPs, we're supposed to count from PC + 4 to calculate the number of jumps needed in a `beq` or `bne` operation. But what if there isn't any other operation that come after this `beq` or `bne`?

For example:

```
     addi $4, $3, 40
     addi $5, $3, 0
loop:lw $6, 0($5)
     addi $6, $6, 1
     sw $6, 0($5)
     addi $5, $5, 4
     slt $6, $5, $4
     bne $6, $zero, loop
```

Would there be a PC + 4 in this case? If not how do i calculate the immediate field in order to find the hexadecimal encoding for the last instruction?

Thank you very much for reading, would greatly appreciate any help rendered!

Comment: An address such as PC+4 is just a number - that number *exists*, whether or not you placed any instruction at that address.  (And it's not really valid to omit that instruction, anyway - that address WILL be executed once the loop completes, with no explicit instruction there you've just given up all control of what the program does.)

Comment: hey, thank you very much for replying. Pardon me if I didn't understand you correctly. Am I right to say that I would need to jump back 6 times to hit the 'loop' label so my immediate value will be -6?

Comment: You're showing a code fragment.  Don't confuse a code fragment with a working program.

Comment: Echoing @jasonharper, you had better put an instruction after the `bne` if you know what's good for you. Because whatever comes after the `bne` is going to execute in the branch delay slot whether you like it or not. (Even if you ignore branch delay slots, it's going to execute if the branch is not taken.) If you don't explicitly put anything there, then you're at the mercy of whatever happens to be there already (or if the stars align just right, you take a page fault because the next instruction is on an invalid page).

Comment: @RaymondChen, we can tell that the OP is using a MIPS system without branch delay slots, by the PC+4.  When MIPS has branch delay slots, branches would be relative to PC+8.

Comment: @ErikEidt, thanks for replying as well! yes I am aware that it is a code fragment. What I'm concerned about here is how to calculate the immediate value for the hexadecimal encoding of the last ```bne``` instruction :)

Comment: @ErikEidt Good call, I missed that detail. My brain just substituted `PC+8` automatically.

Comment: Yes, the branch immediate should be -6.  A value of 0 would continue sequential execution, and a value of -1 would branch to self.

Comment: @ErikEidt, appreciate the answer! Thank you to the rest of you guys as well. I managed to learn more than I was hoping. have a good day!!

Comment: @ErikEidt MIPS isn't ARM, branch offsets are relative to the instruction in the branch delay slot (PC+4), AFAIK.

Comment: @EOF, yes, it is confusing following all the revisions over the last 35+ years.  From [MIPS I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#CPU_instructions) "Control is transferred to the address computed by shifting the 16-bit offset left by two bits, sign-extending the 18-bit result, and adding the 32-bit sign-extended result to the sum of the program counter (instruction address) and 8."

Comment: @ErikEidt Great, you have found an error in wikipedia. From *MIPS® Architecture For Programmers
Volume II-A: The MIPS64® Instruction
Set Reference Manual*: "Description: branch
B offset is the assembly idiom used to denote an unconditional branch. The actual instruction is interpreted by the
hardware as BEQ r0, r0, offset.
An 18-bit signed offset (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits) is added to the address of the instruction following
the branch (not the branch itself), in the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative effective target address."